# PDF - Ligature mapping in CMap

Tags: ios, pdf, unicode

I have a pdf which have following mapping:

```
<019A> <0074>
<039E> <00A9>
<019F> <00740069>
<01B5> <0075>
<01C0> <0076>
<01C7> <0079>
<03EC> <0030>
```

The mapping, cid <019F> represent ligature ti.

In mapping \u0074 -> t and \u0069 -> i (hence) ligature ti.

How do I get actual ligature unicode? or I have to keep the track for such pattern and replace cid mapping with actual unicode of the ligature?

Thanks.

Comment: Unicode doesn't have a "ti" ligature character. Where does this CMap come from?

Comment: It was embedded in PDF. :(

Comment: looks like have to track it programmatically.

Comment: Yes, you have to.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, for every character code you cannot assume that there is only one unicode character in the mapping. You will have to take output of both the characters. It can be even more that two characters in unicode. Some fonts have ligatures for "ffl" as well.

Also to be noted here Unicode specification also has special single character definitions for ligatures as well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature
It's possible the special ligature unicode characters may be used in the mapping.